# Textual editing of ArcGIS MapServer?

Tags: labeling, symbology, map-service, arcgis-explorer, arcgis-online-webmap

Is there a way to use a text editor to edit the various layers of an ArcGIS MapServer?

[This](https://gisservices.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NYS_Streets/MapServer) is the service I'm working with.

Here's my scenario: I'm using ArcGIS Online to create a custom WebMap that will be viewed in ArcGIS Explorer for iOS. The MapServer layers already have symbol and label info included, but because the iOS device has a Retina display, the symbol widths and text sizes are unreadably small. My solution was to globally double these values, but I can't do so in ArcGIS Online without losing the existing symbology (things like highway shields that aren't editable in ArcGIS Online).

As a non-professional Mac user, I don't have any other ArcGIS applications at my disposal, but can I download the layers somehow, edit them in a text application, and re-upload to the WebMap from a file?

Comment: You might be able to fashion a proxy to rewrite the service stream, if the anno is rendered client side, otherwise I expect this is impossible (and even the proxy would require advanced network programming skill).

Comment: If I click on the various layers at that link, I can read the underlying text, including the "Drawing Info" that I'd want to edit. Is there a way to export and re-save this text in some format, ideally as a batch but if necessary as individual layers?

Comment: You have a causality issue here: The properties are cooked into the raw service, and the application generates that text based on the binary content. You *cannot* generally modify the output and post it back into the service (the service is mostly read-only). You *can* republish the data into a second service with different properties.

Comment: That should be fine; I don’t need to change the service, I can add the layers to my web map from a file. But I don’t know what kind of file I should create.